# How to hide current fragment

Tags: android-fragments, back-stack

The title pretty much sums it. I want to get the current fragment in which a view is residing and **onclick** of the view hide the current Fragment . I know i can use replace to remove it and add an other but i only want to hide the current fragment . my fragment class is

```
public class Article extends Fragment
    {
        ImageView Backing,SearchIcon;

        ListView listView;

        EditText textToSearch;

        Activity context;

        String url="http://tables.php";

        View V; //SET THE FRAGMENTS VIEW AS A CLASS VARIABLE HERE


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
             if(V == null)
             { 
                V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article, container, false);

                context = getActivity();

                listView = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.art_listview);

                Backing = (ImageView)V.findViewById(R.id.art_back);

                SearchIcon = (ImageView)V.findViewById(R.id.search_icon);

                listView = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.art_listview);

                textToSearch = (EditText)V.findViewById(R.id.art_search_ev);

                eventHandling();

                new ArticleTask(getActivity(), url, listView).execute(url);
             }

             else
                { //IF ALREADY INSTANTIATED USE SAME OLD V 
                  //  ((ViewGroup)V.getParent()).removeView(V);
                }

            return V;// return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```